# C++ Library for modifying a ZIP file in place

Tags: c++, zip, archive

I'm looking for a way to add or remove files to/from an existing ZIP archive, or any other archive format for that matter as long as there are cross platform APIs, without having to rewrite a new zip file with new files added to it, or sans items deleted from it.

With ZIP files, the catalog is placed at the end of the file so that, and some parts of the zip file will likely have to be rewritten each time.  I'm just trying to avoid having to rewrite the whole thing every time.  The archive files I'm looking at dealing with will be large, and speed is important.

Is there any C++ library out there that does what I'm looking for?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Zipios++](http://zipios.sourceforge.net/) provides direct access to files inside ZIP archives.

Comment: Unfortunately Zipios++ is only for Linux, I couldn't make it compile on Windows :/

Comment: @LukaszCzerwinski There shouldn't be any OS-specific functionality, so compile failures are likely from library incompatibility. I suspect you could get it to compile with some perseverance.

Comment: What's much more important, at the time of this writing Zipios still doesn't seem to support Zip64. So if you keep adding files to your archive and it eventually grows above 4 GiB, you're in trouble. (Same if the amount of files grows above 65K).

Answer (score 1):

[miniz](https://github.com/richgel999/miniz) library allows you to append a file to an existing archive without rewriting it with one function call:

```
mz_zip_error error = MZ_ZIP_NO_ERROR;
mz_bool status = mz_zip_add_mem_to_archive_file_in_place_v2("foo.zip", "bar.txt", "Test", 4, "Comment", 7, MZ_BEST_COMPRESSION, &error);
```

Comment: It also supports Zip64, so no (practical) limits on size and number of files.

Answer (score 0):

Several zip libraries are available, two of the leading libraries are:

http://www.gzip.org/

http://www.info-zip.org/

-Adam

Comment: Alas, the 7zip API is Windows only last time I checked.

Comment: No matter, the 7zip SDK supports the LZMA compression standard, but doesn't appear to have easy support for zip.  The two more common libraries are now listed above.

Comment: http://www.zlib.net/ is the correct address for the library related to gzip (the URL above is for a site mostly about an executable, not a library).

Comment: GZip and ZLib are not "zip" files though.

Comment: Zlib does require extra work to support the zip archive format, but the compression is the same.  Sounds like Zipios++ is exactly what he's after, though.  I'll leave this up for others to reference.